# Groups isomorphic to $S_{4}/N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Let $G = S_4$ be a group, $N = \{1, (1, 2)(3, 4), (1, 3)(2, 4), (1, 4)(2, 3)\}$ a normal subgroup of G.
It's easy to see that $G/N$, the set of cosets is $G/N = \{a, b, c\}$, where

$$a = \{(1), (1, 2)(3, 4), (1, 3)(2, 4), (1, 4)(2, 3)\},$$
$$b = \{(1, 3)(1, 2), (2, 3)(2, 4), (1, 2)(1, 4), (1, 4)(1, 3)\},$$
$$c = \{(1, 2)(1, 3), (2, 4)(2, 3), (1, 4)(1, 2), (1, 3)(1, 4)\}.$$

The question that I'm trying to solve is asking me to determine which known group $G/N$ is isomorphic to.

It's easy to check that the group of elements of $a, b, c$ is the alternating group $A_4$, but this isn't what the question is asking. Perhaps an intuitive question to ask would be "how should I view the elements of $G/N$?

Comment: This was asked a few days ago.

Comment: A lot of what you've written above isn't quite correct. $N$ is a normal subgroup of $S_{4}$ of order $4$, and $G = S_{4}$ has order $24$, so the quotient group $G/N$ has order $|G|/|N| = 6$. You could explicitly write out what the cosets of $N$ in $G$ are, but it's probably cleaner to think about what the possible groups of order $6$ are up to isomorphism.

Comment: @Alex_Wertheim I've embarrassingly appeared to have taken $G = A_4$ instead of $S_4$, which would have been obvious if I checked the quotient group order. Thanks!

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff I would delete this but it has already been answered and it appears to not be good practice to do so. Perhaps my mistake can be learned from in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\;\left|S_4/N\right|=6\implies S_4/N=C_6\;\;or\;\;S_3\;$, because these two are the only groups of order six up to isomorphism.

Yet the first option is possible iff $\;[S_4,S_4]=A_4\le N\;$ , so it actually is the second one.